# Get Percentage of Gas Price Solidity, Ethereum

Tags: ethereum, solidity

How can I multiply a `uint` by a decimal fraction integer? This is what I have so far - I am explicitly converting the decimal fraction integer to type `uint`. Will this have unintended consequences?

```
uint gasPriceInWei = tx.gasprice * 1000000000;
uint percentOfGasPrice = uint(transactionCostInWei) * uint(.1);
```

Comment: For Ethereum questions, please ask this question on the [**Ethereum StackExchange**](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com) instead :)

Comment: Will do @ObsidianAge

Comment: @ObsidianAge this is a Solidity related programming question. I see no reason why that shouldn’t be allowed on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Solidity does not support floating point numbers (yet). You need to store as an integer and convert on the client side. See the note [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#fixed-point-numbers).